# Taking values from tables in a single file using python

Tags: python, pandas

everyone. Sooo I am trying to write a script in order to read the values from a text file.  These values are arranged in the following way:

```
   130   1,  1     0
   11    3,  1   1/3
    1   -3,  2   1/6
    9    1,  2   1/2
   12    1,  2  -1/2
    9   -3,  1  -1/3
   26    1,  1   1/2
   20    1,  2     0
   26    1,  1  -1/2
```

I tried using read_csv from pandas

```
x=pd.read_csv('myfile.txt',names=['num','c','l','y'], sep='\s+',engine='python')
```

and it works, except I cannot get rid of the comma from the second column. This is the output:

```
     num    c  l     y
0    130   1,  1     0
1     11   3,  1   1/3
2      1  -3,  2   1/6
3      9   1,  2   1/2
4     12   1,  2  -1/2
..   ...  ... ..   ...
```

I also tried using sep='\s+[,]' or something like that, but at the end I always get the whole table in the 'num' column and the rest just appear as NaN.

Hopefull someone can help. I know it's just a simple comma, but I have tried multiple things and I cannot get rid of it

Comment: For an optional `","` wouldn't you want to use `sep=',?\s+'`? Otherwise, could you strip the `","` and convert the datatype after you read it in?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your regex expects a comma *after* a series of whitespaces, but it should be the other way. Also, you haven't made the comma optional. Your regular expression can be like this:

```py
x=pd.read_csv('myfile.txt', names=['num','c','l','y'], sep="\,?\s+",engine='python')
```

**Explaination**: Sep can be an optional comma (\,?) followed by a series of whitespaces.

Alternatively, you can use a lambda to remove the comma from that column!

```py
x["c"] = x["c"].apply(lambda x: x.split(",")[0])
```

or

```py
x["c"] = x["c"].apply(lambda x: x[:-1])
```

Result:

```
   num   c  l     y
0  130   1  1     0
1   11   3  1   1/3
2    1  -3  2   1/6
3    9   1  2   1/2
4   12   1  2  -1/2
5    9  -3  1  -1/3
6   26   1  1   1/2
7   20   1  2     0
8   26   1  1  -1/2
```